# backTrasform, lnearComb, coefficients, unmarked

Tags: r, coefficients

I am running an occupancy analysis and I am using "backTransofrm" to estimate the general "p" and "psi". This is my final model:

```
Occupancy:
            Estimate    SE      z P(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -0.391 0.554 -0.706   0.480
dist_water    -0.931 0.571 -1.632   0.103

Detection:
                  Estimate    SE     z P(>|z|)
dist_road             0.67 0.218  3.08 0.00208
trigger_speedfast    -1.12 0.372 -3.01 0.00260
trigger_speedslow    -3.47 1.152 -3.01 0.00260

AIC: 131.4012
```

Then I want to use the backTransform function to estimate the general "p" and "psi" but I do not understand how it manages the factor "trigger_spped low" and "trigger_spped fast" for the detection "p".

Basically I do not understand how "coeffients" works.

Here it is my code:

```
backTransform(linearComb(p1,coefficients = c(1,1,0), type="det"))

Estimate     SE LinComb dist_road trigger_speedfast trigger_speedslow
    0.389 0.0889  -0.451         1                 1                 0
```

I do not want that  R puts "1" in trigger_speedfast and "0" in trigger_speedslow.

Could someone kindly help me?

I expect to try to sole my problem putting the right values on the right variables